# Building a Python extension with bjam (Boost.Build) on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, boost

So far as I can tell what happens is this:

- In `python.jam`, it works out which version of Python I am using and which library directories to look in;
- It adds `-Wl-R` arguments to the `g++` command line to include those directories;
- The `ld` command complains that it does not have a `-R` option.

So either (a) I have a defective version of `ld`, or (b) I need to tell bjam that it needs to use a different option (`-rpath` perhaps?) or that this option is not required.

I must be missing something—I am surely not the first person in history to try to build a Python extension with Boost on Mac OS X—but I can’t figure out where to look next. Any hints?

Update:

The command I am using is

```
bjam
```

If I do `bjam --version`, I get

```
Boost.Build V2 (Milestone 12)
Boost.Jam 03.1.18
```

The toolset used is whatever the default toolset is on Mac OS X.

The compiler is the default compiler on Mac OS X (with the developer tools installed), which is GCC version ‘i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)’.

The linker is the default linker on Mac OS X, which is called `ld` or `ld64`, but which does not have the `-R` option that GNU `ld` has, so I assume it is a special version designed to allow for Mac OS X’s concept of frameworks or whatever. It does not have a `--version` option.

There is a `Jamfile`, which goes like this:

```
import python ;

python-extension _optimor :
    bill_python.cpp
    bill_record_python.cpp
    .. etc ...
    :
    <cxxflags>-fPIC
    ... etc ...
    <variant>debug:<define>DEBUG
    <include>/usr/include/python2.6
    <include>../
    ;
```

It builds OK on Ububtu GNU/Linux.

I am not interested in Boost or `bjam` per se; my only requirement to compile this extension so I can get on with developing the system of which this extension is a small but important part.

Comment: There's insufficient information on your question to answer it. I need to know how you are invoking the build system, i.e. the command you are using and which toolset/compiler/sdk you are using.

Answer (score 3):

I can't tell which version of Boost you have.. BUt the most likely reason for the problem is that you are using the generic "gcc" toolset to build. There's a special toolset for building with the GCC variant that Apple uses in Xcode. Try building with `bjam toolset=darwin` instead.